# Error: android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Tags: android-studio, webservice, android-intent

Estoy intentando ejecutar un Intent pero me da un error al lanzar el intent me muestra el siguiente error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
>   android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

no se porque sucede ese error cuando mando a llamar mi intent, este es el metodo donde intento ejecutar mi intent:

```
public void vistaDetalle(String tituloNoticia, String subtituloNoticia, String imagenNoticia, String descripcionNoticia, Context context, Activity activity) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), DescripcionNoticias.class);
        intent.putExtra("titulon",tituloNoticia);
        intent.putExtra("descripcionn", descripcionNoticia);
        intent.putExtra("imagen", imagenNoticia);
        startActivity(intent);
        getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.left_out);
    }
```

ya he intentado usar getActivity() y otros metodos pero ninguno me funciona,
esta es la clase completa:

```
public class Inicio extends Fragment implements noticiasAdapter.OnEventMovieListener, Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener{

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Noticias> noticias;
    private noticiasAdapter noticiasadapter;
    public static final String TAG = Noticias.class.getName();

    RequestQueue request;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;

    Context contextApp;

    public Inicio(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.contextApp = context;
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inicio, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        noticias = new ArrayList<>();
        noticiasadapter = new noticiasAdapter(noticias);
        noticiasadapter.setOnEventMovieListener(this);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        request = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        cargarWebService();

        return view;
    }

    private void cargarWebService() {

        String url = "http://192.168.1.81:80/webservicemgrex/listaNoticias.php";
        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
        request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Noticias news = null;
        JSONArray json = response.optJSONArray("inicio");

        try{
            for (int i=0; i<json.length(); i++){
                news = new Noticias();
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(i);

                news.setIdNoticia(jsonObject.optInt("idNoticia"));
                news.setTituloNoticia(jsonObject.optString("tituloNoticia"));
                news.setSubtituloNoticia(jsonObject.getString("subtituloNoticia"));
                news.setImagenNoticia(jsonObject.getString("imagenNoticia"));
                news.setDescripcionNoticia(jsonObject.getString("descripcionNoticia"));
                noticias.add(news);
            }

            noticiasAdapter adapter = new noticiasAdapter(noticias);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            noticiasadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }catch (JSONException e){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error al cargar la informacion del servidor: "+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No se pudo consultar los registros: "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("Error","No se pudo consultar el registro: "+error.toString());
    }

    public void vistaDetalle(String tituloNoticia, String subtituloNoticia, String imagenNoticia, String descripcionNoticia, Context context, Activity activity) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), DescripcionNoticias.class);
        intent.putExtra("titulon",tituloNoticia);
        intent.putExtra("descripcionn", descripcionNoticia);
        intent.putExtra("imagen", imagenNoticia);
        startActivity(intent);
        getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.left_out);
    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Esta es mi clase desde donde lo mando a llamar, cuando se ejecuta el onclick trato de llamar a mi metodo vistaDetalle:

```
public class noticiasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<noticiasAdapter.NoticiasViewHolder> {

    private List<Noticias> noticias;
    private OnEventMovieListener onEventMovieListener;
    private Context context;
    public Activity activity;

    public interface OnEventMovieListener{
       }

    public class NoticiasViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener, View.OnClickListener {

        TextView tituloNoticia;
        TextView subtituloNoticia;
        ImageView imagenNoticia;
        TextView descripcionNoticia;
        FloatingActionButton favoritos;
        Button showMore;
        private int contador = 0;

        public NoticiasViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);

            tituloNoticia = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tituloNoticia);
            subtituloNoticia = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtituloNoticia);
            imagenNoticia = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagenNotica);
            descripcionNoticia = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.descripcionNoticias);

            favoritos = (FloatingActionButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
            favoritos.setOnClickListener(this);

            showMore = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.showMore);
            showMore.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch(view.getId()){
                case R.id.floatingActionButton:
                    if (contador == 0){
                        favoritos.setImageResource(R.drawable.likedcolor);
                        contador = contador + 1;
                        Noticias fav = noticias.get(getAdapterPosition());
                        noticiasWebService noti = new noticiasWebService();
                        noti.update(fav.getTituloNoticia(), fav.getSubtituloNoticia(), fav.getImagenNoticia(), fav.getDescripcionNoticia(), context);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Se añadio a tus favoritos ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else if (contador == 1){
                        favoritos.setImageResource(R.drawable.unliked);
                        contador = contador - 1;
                        Noticias fav = noticias.get(getAdapterPosition());
                        noticiasWebService noti = new noticiasWebService();
                        noti.deleteRegistro(fav.getTituloNoticia(), context);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Se elimino de tus favoritos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.showMore:
                    Noticias news = noticias.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    Inicio inicio = new Inicio();
                    inicio.vistaDetalle(news.getTituloNoticia(), news.getSubtituloNoticia(), news.getImagenNoticia(), news.getDescripcionNoticia(),context, activity );
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

        }
    }

    public noticiasAdapter(List<Noticias> noticias){
        this.noticias = noticias;
    }

    @Override
    public NoticiasViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_noticias, parent, false);
        context = parent.getContext();
        return new NoticiasViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NoticiasViewHolder holder, int position){

        Noticias news = noticias.get(position);

        holder.tituloNoticia.setText(news.getTituloNoticia());
        holder.subtituloNoticia.setText(news.getSubtituloNoticia());
        final String url = new String(news.getImagenNoticia());
        if(url.isEmpty()){
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.nofound).into(holder.imagenNoticia);
        }else {
            Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(holder.imagenNoticia);
        }
        holder.descripcionNoticia.setText(news.getDescripcionNoticia());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return noticias.size();
    }

    public OnEventMovieListener getOnEventMovieListener() {
        return onEventMovieListener;
    }

    public void setOnEventMovieListener(OnEventMovieListener onEventMovieListener){
        this.onEventMovieListener = onEventMovieListener;
    }
}
```

y este es el metodo:

```
 case R.id.showMore:
                    Noticias news = noticias.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    Inicio inicio = new Inicio();
                    inicio.vistaDetalle(news.getTituloNoticia(), news.getSubtituloNoticia(), news.getImagenNoticia(), news.getDescripcionNoticia(),context, activity );
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
```

Estas es la clase que estoy intentando llamar DescripcionNoticia.class:

public class DescripcionNoticias extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TextView tituloNoticiaDescripcion;
TextView noticiaCompleta;
ImageView imagenNoticiaCompleta;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_descripcion_noticias);

    //Toolbar de la aplicacion en la vista principal
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Sección 15");
    toolbar.setSubtitle("Nota completa");

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    String tituloNoticia = getIntent().getExtras().getString("titulon");
    String descripcionNoticia = getIntent().getExtras().getString("descripcionn");
    String imagenNoticia = getIntent().getExtras().getString("imagen");

    tituloNoticiaDescripcion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tituloDesNoticia);
    noticiaCompleta = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.noticiaCompleta);
    imagenNoticiaCompleta = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagenNoticiaCompleta);

    tituloNoticiaDescripcion.setText(tituloNoticia);
    noticiaCompleta.setText(descripcionNoticia);
    imagenNoticiaCompleta.setImageResource(R.drawable.noticiauno);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_out, R.anim.left_in);
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Este es el error completo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Enrique, usa getActivity() como contexto y revisa el LogCat, probablemente tienes otro tipo de problema.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ya lo solucione, lo único que hice fue cambiar el método al adaptador y le paso el context de la siguiente forma:

Creo una variable

private Context context;

y en el metodo onCreateViewHolder le asigno el siguiente valor:

context = parent.getContext();

y en mi metodo donde ejecuto el intent lo hago de esta forma, solamente le paso la variable contex:

```
case R.id.showMore:
                    Noticias news = noticias.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DescripcionNoticias.class);
                    intent.putExtra("titulon",news.getTituloNoticia());
                    intent.putExtra("descripcionn", news.getDescripcionNoticia());
                    intent.putExtra("imagen", news.getImagenNoticia());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                default:
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Iniciar Activity desde Fragment.

Si deseas realizar un Intent para abrir una Activity desde un Fragment, debes usar como contexto `getActivity()`, de esta forma obtienes el contexto de la Actividad que contiene el Fragment.

Ejemplo:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DescripcionNoticias.class);
  startActivity(intent);

  //*Incorrecto.
  //Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), DescripcionNoticias.class);
```

Obviamente la `Activity` a iniciar debe estar registrada en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`

Si obtienes un error al usar `getActivity()` seguramente es provocado por otra causa, debes revisar el `LogCat` y agregar esa información a tu pregunta.

Comment: Ya agregue el erro completo que me da si uso getActivity(), pero sigo sin entender porque me da ese error porque todas las Acivity que tengo estan en el AndroidManifest

Answer (score -3):

Intenta con esto si lo lanzas desde un fragmento:

```
public void vistaDetalle(String tituloNoticia, String subtituloNoticia, String 
imagenNoticia, String descripcionNoticia, Context context, Activity activity) 
{
 try
 {
  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),DescripcionNoticias.class);
  intent.putExtra("titulon",tituloNoticia);
  intent.putExtra("descripcionn", descripcionNoticia);
  intent.putExtra("imagen", imagenNoticia);
  startActivity(intent);
 }
 catch (Exception e) 
 {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }

 }
```

Si lo lanzas desde un Activity sería:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, DescripcionNoticias.class);
```

Comment: ya agregue la clase por la que preguntas pero el error es al intentar ejecutar el activity con el intent

Comment: De echo esa solución que pusiste no resuelve el problema porque el problema es que el getActivity() o el getContext() marca el error, y no puedo llamarlo con .this porque marca error también.